# Why Paypal expands boxes at checkout page?

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal on my ecommerce site, at check out page after filling billing information on woocommerce when I put card detail on Paypal express it goes full screen. Why it zoom in? I am facing this error on android. On ios it is working fine. Please help. thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find issue for this? I am having same problem